# Error C3352 (the specified function does not match the delegate type)

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I know there are tons of answers to this error message out there, but I failed to find a solution for my problem. I am playing with a function call from unmanaged C++ through C++/CLI into C#. The tricky part is that I want to pass a C callback function pointer down to the C# code in the function's parameter list, and then call this callback from the C# code. It works "in principle," but there is one problem that drives me up the walls. (Using Visual Studio 2022 17.6.5)

This C# class is compiled into an assembly:

```cs
namespace CsWorker
{
    public class CsWorkerClass
    {
        public delegate int Callback();
        public int DoSomething(int i, Callback cb)
        {
            return i+cb();
        }
    }
}
```

I created a C++/CLI wrapper class around the assembly which is compiled into a separate DLL:

(header file WrapperClass.h)

```cpp
class WorkerClass;

class __declspec(dllexport) WrapperClass
{
public:
    using tCallback = int (*)(void);
    WrapperClass();
    ~WrapperClass();
    int DoSomething(int i, tCallback cb);
private:
    WorkerClass* m_pWorker{};
};
```

(implementation file WrapperClass.cpp)

```cpp
#include "WrapperClass.h"
#include <msclr/auto_gcroot.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace CsWorker;

class WorkerClass
{
public:
    static int MyCallback()
    {
        return 77;
    }
    int DoSomething(int i, int(*cb)(void))
    {
        // The static_assert is not triggered
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(cb), decltype(&MyCallback)>);
        // The following line compiles
        /*return*/ m_pWorker->DoSomething(i, gcnew CsWorker::CsWorkerClass::Callback(&MyCallback));
        // This line doesn't compile
        // error C3352: 'int (__cdecl *__cdecl cb)(void)': the specified function does not match the delegate type 'int (void)'
        return m_pWorker->DoSomething(i, gcnew CsWorker::CsWorkerClass::Callback(cb));
    }
    msclr::auto_gcroot<CsWorkerClass^> m_pWorker{};
};

WrapperClass::WrapperClass()
{
    m_pWorker = new WorkerClass;
    m_pWorker->m_pWorker = gcnew CsWorkerClass;
}

WrapperClass::~WrapperClass()
{
    delete m_pWorker;
}

int WrapperClass::DoSomething(int i, tCallback cb)
{
    return m_pWorker->DoSomething(i, cb);
}
```

Why can the line that passes `&MyCallback` compile and the line that passes `cb` create an error, when the types of both arguments are identical? And what is the problem converting an `int(void)` function into an `int(void)` delegate?

Answer (score -1):

A colleague pointed me to the article [C++/CLI: Storing Lambda in a Delegate](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1170306/Cplusplus-CLI-Storing-Lambda-in-a-Delegate?msg=5956034#xx5956034xx) on CodeProject which provided a solution to my problem. TBH, I don't claim to understand it, but it works!